# Regex - Include space before only when one OR item is match

Tags: regex, regex-group

Is there a way to include a space before an item of Or structure only when match to one of it ? The items can repeat inside string.

REGEX:

```
^([A-ZÁÂÉÊÍÓÔÚ][a-záãâéêíóõôúç]+)([(e|da|das|de|do|dos)]*[\s][A-ZÁÂÉÊÍÓÔÚ][a-záãâéêíóõôúç]+)+$
```

Space before one of this items (mandatory):  `[(e|da|das|de|do|dos)]`

Result I want:

`Paulo César Oliveira` (this is working)
`Antonio Carlos da Silva` **(must have ONE space before "da")**
`João da Silva dos Santos e Souza` **(must have ONE space before "da", "dos" and "e"**)

Comment: Something like  https://regex101.com/r/LF4GC4/1 ? Could you please clarify what strings must match and those must not and why?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew There area two groups in Regex I submited:  1)  ([A-ZÁÂÉÊÍÓÔÚ][a-záãâéêíóõôúç]+)  and 2)  ([(e|da|das|de|do|dos)]*[\s][A-ZÁÂÉÊÍÓÔÚ][a-záãâéêíóõôúç]+)+ The first group is for people first name. The second group is for the rest of the name, where could appear or not the strings "e", "da", "das, "de", "do" and "dos"  before other names and mandatoryaly must have ONE space before it (" e", " da", " das", " de", " do" and " dos"), like the examples of names I showed at the end. Please, if you don't understand yet, tell me. Thank you.

Comment: I posted the answer, it seems clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
^\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+(?:(?:\s(?:e|d(?:[ao]s|[aeo])))?\s\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)+$
^[A-ZÁÂÉÊÍÓÔÚ][a-záãâéêíóõôúç]+(?:(?:\s(?:e|d(?:[ao]s|[aeo])))?\s[A-ZÁÂÉÊÍÓÔÚ][a-záãâéêíóõôúç]+)+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LF4GC4/3). `\p{Lu}` and `\p{Ll}` may be unsupported by your regex engine, then keep on using your character classes.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+` - an uppercase letter followed with one or more lowercase letters
- `(?:(?:\s(?:e|d(?:[ao]s|[aeo])))?\s\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)+` - one or more occurrences of the following patterns:

  - `(?:\s(?:e|d(?:[ao]s|[aeo])))?` - an optional occurrence of:

    - `\s` - a whitespaces
    - `(?:e|d(?:[ao]s|[aeo]))` - `e` or `d` followed with either `os`/`as` or `a`, `e`, `o`
  - `\s` - a whitespaces
  - `\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+` - an uppercase letter followed with one or more lowercase letters
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Stribizew The first example you provide it's working but is accepting more than one space between the words. BUT THE SECOND ONE IS PERFECT ! THANK YOU SO MUCH !!!

Comment: @AdalbertoJoséBrasaca They both only allow one whitespace, `\s` only matches a single one. See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LF4GC4/4).

Comment: Stribizew Strange behavior from regex101. I open the page and inserted one more  space between the names you put there and it accepted the string. But when I typed a name from the start it worked. You're right ! Thank you again.

Comment: @AdalbertoJoséBrasaca `\s` matches line breaks, that is why I replaced it with `\h` in the PCRE demo. `\h` only matches horizontal whitespace.